# c# Progress Bar IsIndeterminate animation stuck in GUI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I got this code below that is called whenever a button is clicked. Now, since it's using Telnet and I had to add a bunch of Thread.Sleep(), this method takes a good 5-7 seconds to execute.

I was wondering if theres a way to have the animation of the Progress Bar at the same time as this run to let the user know that everything is fine.

Thanks.

```
private void rack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                progressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;

                // Extrait le nom du rack sélectionné 
                selectedRack = (sender as Button).Content.ToString().ToLower();

                // Console Update
                console.Text += "Connexion en cours...";

                // Ouvre la connection au PDU
                clientPDU = this.getConnectionPDU();

                // S'assure que la connection fut éffectué correctement
                if (clientPDU != null)
                {
                    // Disable les autres racks
                    for (int i = 65; i < 71; i++)
                    {
                        Button btn = (Button)FindName("rack_" + ((char)i));
                        if (btn.Content.ToString().ToLower() != selectedRack)
                            btn.IsEnabled = false;
                    }

                    // Active Rafraichir et Déconnecter
                    refresh.IsEnabled = true;
                    disconnect.IsEnabled = true;

                    // Console Update
                    console.Text += "\nConnexion établie";

                    // Mettre à jour les Port qui sont ouvert/fermé
                    this.getPortStatus();

                    // Active les boutons en correspondance à ce qui est On et Off
                    this.setButtonStatus();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Console Update
                    console.Text += "\n\nConnexion Impossible. Veuillez réessayer...\n";
                }

                // Scroll to end
                scroller.ScrollToEnd();

                progressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
            }
```

Comment: Do your `Thread.Sleep()` in non-UI thread?

Comment: This is very easy to solve once you understand the concept behind [async/await](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) tasks. Using async/await, prevents the blocking thread that is freezing up your UI or your progress bar. I use this method myself whenever I work with older WinForms applications.

Comment: The `rack_Click` method is running on the UI thread so none of the UI elements can update while this code is running. You need to run this on a background thread to enable the UI to update while it is running.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the IsIndeterminate property to false and specify values for the progress bar throughout the operation in order to provide for animation of the progressbar.:

```
progressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
// set the maximum for the progressBar
progressBar.Maximum = 100;
// do work and increment value
progressBar.Value++;
```

The following page has an example of a ProgressBar with the IsIndeterminate property set to true and a picture of what the animation looks like (it provides no real user feedback).  The page also has an example with IsIndeterminate set to false, but values must be specified.  In this example, the work is done on a separate thread so as to allow for UI interaction while the work is being performed.

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-progressbar-control/

Comment: This is a good alternative to the async/await approach. It's easier to follow and directly addresses the problem with minimal code.

Comment: You should avoid external links unless the content there supports the content that you have **already put in your answer**. Otherwise the value of your answer can be diminished if the link becomes broken.

Comment: I agree that external links should be avoided, but in my humble opinion, this is exactly what the external link in my answer provides (it supports the content in my answer).  To be clear, in my answer, I am stating that "IsIndeterminate" must be set to false in order to provide the user with feedback in the progressBar Control.  The external link provided shows the difference (from a UI perspective) when IsIndeterminate is set to false, and when it is set to true.